# Proper Way To Pass hlint Arguments to ghc-mod?

Tags: haskell, ghc-mod, hlint

I'm trying to lint a file with ghc-mod. I know ghc-mod uses hlint for this and I know that hlint accepts arguments to modify the suggestions it reports. For instance, this works just fine:

```
eric@linux-epth:total-beginner-haskell$ hlint src/Borrower.hs --hint=Generalise
src/Borrower.hs:44:3: Suggestion: Use mappend
Found:
getName br ++
" (" `mappend` show (getMaxBooks br) `mappend` " books)"
Why not:
getName br `Data.Monoid.mappend`
(" (" `mappend` show (getMaxBooks br) `mappend` " books)")

1 hint
```

Here's the format ghc-mod requires for passing arguments to hlint:

```
Usage: ghc-mod lint [-h|--hlintOpt ARG] FILE
```

But none of the variations below produce the hint shown above:

```
eric@linux-epth:total-beginner-haskell$ ghc-mod lint -h hint=Generalise src/Borrower.hs
eric@linux-epth:total-beginner-haskell$ ghc-mod lint --hlintOpt hint=Generalise src/Borrower.hs
eric@linux-epth:total-beginner-haskell$ ghc-mod lint --hlintOpt "--hint=Generalise" src/Borrower.hs
eric@linux-epth:total-beginner-haskell$ ghc-mod lint --hlintOpt '--hint=Generalise' src/Borrower.hs
```

What is the correct format to use with ghc-mod to pass arguments through it to hlint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is a bug of ghc-mod:

Issue: https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/issues/826

It's already fixed and merged to master, but not yet released.

Since the issue's milestone is `v5.8.0.0`, it may be fixed in that release.

I built the `ghc-mod` from latest `master` branch from Github, and confirmed that following command works:

```
$ ghc-mod lint src/Borrower.hs  --hlintOpt='--hint=Generalise.hs'
src/Borrower.hs:1:8: Suggestion: Use mappendFound:  getName br ++    " (" `mappend` show (getMaxBooks br) `mappend` " books)"Why not:  getName br `Data.Monoid.mappend`    (" (" `mappend` show (getMaxBooks br) `mappend` " books)"
```

Here's the step that I executed to build latest `ghc-mod` from Github.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod
$ cd ghc-mod
$ stack init --ignore-subdirs --solver
$ stack build
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I used "stack install ghc-mod" to get ghc mod. I have: "ghc-mod version 5.6.0.0 compiled by GHC 8.0.1". Could you tell me how to build from Github master like you did? Thank you.

Comment: Great - thanks! One last question: does it make a difference which directory I clone the repo into?

Comment: @ericky I think not